# How can I join 2 csv files using python only and not using scala or creating temptables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am pretty new to superfunnel and web attribution using python and I am trying to get find a solution to my problem. I have 2 csv files  (url and visits)

```
url.csv
short_code
full_url
time_created
user_id
premium_user
country

visits.csv
short_code
visit_time
browser_type
version
platform
ipaddress
country
```

I am writing a python code to get the following

```
1. Return urls which only have visitors from the same country as the url was created from

2. Get the URL with the shortest time between when the URL was created and when the first visit was recorded

3. Gets a count of visits to each short code by each unique visitor
```

below is my code, which simply imports data from my cloud

link to my files https://www.dropbox.com/s/u193iv6ybeges92/url.csv?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3vmdra41p3qjgv/visits.csv?dl=0

```
import csv
import requests

from pprint import pprint


def same_country_only(visits, urls):
    """Return urls which only have visitors from the same country as the url was created from"""
    pass


def shortest_first_visit(visits, urls):
    """Get the URL with the shortest time between when the URL was created and when the first visit was recorded"""
    pass


def unique_visitors(visits, urls):
    """Gets a count of visits to each short code by each unique visitor"""
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls_response = requests.get('<<my_url>>').text
    urls_dr = csv.DictReader(urls_response.splitlines(), delimiter=',')    
    urls = [dict(url) for url in urls_dr]
    pprint(urls[0]) # example format

    print('\n' + '*' * 60 + '\n')

    visits_response = requests.get('<<my_url>>').text
    visits_dr = csv.DictReader(visits_response.splitlines(), delimiter=',')    
    visits = [dict(visit) for visit in visits_dr]
    pprint(visits[0]) # example format

    print('\n' + '*' * 60 + '\n')

    pprint(same_country_only(visits, urls))
    pprint(shortest_first_visit(visits, urls))
    pprint(unique_visitors(visits, urls))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Sample Csv's (First Column is the header)

url.csv

```
id  short_cod   long_url    created_ti  creator_id  premium country
1   GTq6Bl  https://w   2018-07-2   78  FALSE   CA
2   EmazTI  https://as  2018-07-2   124 FALSE   GB
3   tT54Bl  https://bi  2018-07-2   97  FALSE   GBG4
4   6ZTSle  https://gi  2018-07-2   98  FALSE   US
5   3akWjJ  https://e   2018-07-2   11  FALSE   JP
6   m7NoUy  https://bl  2018-07-2   34  TRUE    JP
7   lszSBy  https://m   2018-07-2   90  FALSE   US
8   PnTavE  https://ha  2018-07-2   1   FALSE   GB
9   QkXxbV  https://d   2018-07-2   109 FALSE   CN
```

visits.csv

```
browser_t   visit_time  short_cod   country platform    ip_address
Chrome  2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  IT  Windows 78.110.51.215
Firefox 2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  IT  Linux   27.243.245.232
Chrome  2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  JP  Mac OS  97.155.155.73
Chrome  2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  RU  Linux   85.201.130.148
Chrome  2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  GB  Linux   26.90.189.168
Chrome  2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  CN  Android 58.203.242.175
Edge    2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  KR  Windows 84.11.120.228
Safari  2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  KR  iOS 46.72.81.132
Firefox 2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  IT  Linux   30.47.125.89F10
Safari  2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  CA  iOS 85.245.10.160
Firefox 2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  RU  Windows 43.13.144.48
Chrome  2018-07-2   GTq6Bl  IT  Android 65.74.182.22
```

Comment: is this your homework? try asking a specific question with a minimal example.

Comment: its not any homework, I am doing the same joins using sparkSQL and I want to compare the performance if I used only python. In this way I can migrate my ETL chain to pure python. And also i am not that good at pure python so asking for help

Comment: then narrow to specific question, which is helpable, the whole workflow is not - SO is rather an advice site, not a free programming service

Comment: this is the bare minimum i can cut down to, instead of simply asking  """Return urls which only have visitors from the same country as the url was created from""" I have made an effort to provide you with examples and also the files. Also I have made the template. I know its not a free programming site, neither do i expect you to provide complete solution but just some pointers as to how I go about.

Comment: So you want a function `check_country(url, country)`? What are examples of urls and countries?

Comment: url.csv:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/u193iv6ybeges92/url.csv?dl=0 visits.csv: 
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3vmdra41p3qjgv/visits.csv?dl=0

Comment: no dropbox please - better put parts of csv to question. your task is essentially a SQL `join` operation on two tables `url` and `visits`, get the csv files inside pandas dataframes, merge two dataframes on `country` field and select the urls from that table.

Comment: urls.csv                                                                                                              d short_cod long_url created_ti creator_id premium country
1 GTq6Bl https://w 2018-07-2 78 FALSE CA
2 EmazTI https://as 2018-07-2 124 FALSE GB
visits.csv browser_t visit_time short_cod country platform ip_address
Chrome 2018-07-2 GTq6Bl IT Windows 78.110.51.215
Firefox 2018-07-2 GTq6Bl IT Linux 27.243.245.232
Chrome 2018-07-2 GTq6Bl JP Mac OS 97.155.155.73
Chrome 2018-07-2 GTq6Bl RU Linux 85.201.130.148

Comment: Ravi, make you question easy to answer, do not htrough things in comments, put it into your orginal question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178154/discussion-between-ravi-and-epo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use panda's to achieve this. Panda's has a feature to join the 2 csv's based on common columns. merge is the key used for joining.